# Iterate array and find the sum between a range of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, If I pass the number 10 and the array `[1, 2, 4, 4]` the function should if the array was `[4,2,1,1]` the function should return false, because the sum was not between 2 numbers.

Comment: Any two numbers, or two adjacent numbers? Also, is the recursion a requirement?

Comment: Any two @mhodges

Comment: Can we get answers with explinations of how to arrive at the correct answer? Also, I'd like to point out that your function should really only return a single `type`. If I were using this I would expect a boolean to be returned, not null or an array.

Comment: I think this could be more efficient if you first sort the array and then try to match. In case of time complexity this may result better approach.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) functions to check if the sum of any two numbers in the given array equals the passed argument - see demo below:

```js
function solution(num, array) {
  return array.some(function(e, i) {
    return (num - e + array.find(function(c, k) {
      return c == e && i != k
    })) == num;
  });
}


console.log(solution(8, [-1, 2, 3, 4]), solution(8, [-1, 4, 3, 4]), solution(8, [4,3,45,2,5,3]));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it like this with no recursion, just looping over the elements and the next ones and exit the loop as soon as a solution is found:

```js
function solution(n, arr) {
    if (n < 0) return null;
    if (n === 0) return [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var first = arr[i]; // first addend
        for (var j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) { // considering only next elements in the array
            if (first + arr[j] === n) {
                console.log(`found solution with ${first} and ${arr[j]}`);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log('no solution found');
    return false;
}

console.log(solution(8, [4, 3, 45, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(solution(8, [-1, 2, 3, 4]));
```

Answer (score 0):

The naive implementation for checking for a sum of two numbers is a nested loop, see below:

```
function isSumInArray(sum, array) {
    for (let i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (let j=0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] + array[j] === sum && i !== j) {
                return true 
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are better ways to implement this, but I'm choosing it because I think it's the most simplistic to understand. You're going through the array twice here, and if the two numbers are equal to your desired sum (and they are not the same number in the array), then return true. If none of the combinations satisfy this condition, return false.

Comment: You can start j at i+1 instead of 0, to avoid repetition, example : [1,2,3,4], when you check 1 with 2, there is no need to check 2 with 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

for any tow numbers in array

```js
function test(array , n)
{
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
  {
    for(var j=0;j<array.length ; j++)
      if(array[i] + array[j] == n && i != j)
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,2];
console.log(test(array , 1));
console.log(test(array , 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

For each element, you need to "do the math" with every other element to see if they sum correctly.

The simplest implementation is a nested loop O(N^2).

Pseudocode:

```
def solution(list, target)
  for each element e1 in list
    for each element e2 in list
      if e2 is e1 
        continue
      end if
      if e1 + e2 is target
        return true
      end if
    loop
  loop
  return false
end def
```

Code:

```js
function solution(list, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const e1 = list[i];
        for(let j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
            const e2 = list[j];
            if(i === j) { continue; }
            if(e1 + e2 === target) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(solution([1,2,3,4,5], 2));
```

The next simplest solution is to realise that addition (ie. the sum operation) is commutative. This means that the order of the operands does not matter. 1+2 is the same as 2+1. This means that we need not re-calculate the sums for numbers we have already visited in the outer loop because as we advance we calculate the sum for a + b and by definition therefore cover b + a. The overall complexity remains the same though: O(N^2) (AFAICT).

Pseudocode:

```
def solution(list, target)
  for each element e1 in list
    for each element e2 that is to the right of e1 in list
      if e1 + e2 is target
        return true
      end if
    loop
  loop
  return false
end def
```

Code:

```js
function solution(list, target) {
    for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const e1 = list[i];
        for(let j = i+1; j < list.length; j++) {
            const e2 = list[j];
            if(e1 + e2 === target) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(solution([1,2,3,4,5], 5));
```

A better solution is to combine the two facts that addition is commutative and that we know what to look for without having to actually enumerate the list a second time. i.e. if `a` is the current element, then we know we want `a + x = target` so `x` can be easily calculated (it is the difference). By using an O(1) lookup data structure we can replace the inner loop and make the algorithm O(N) overall.

To re-state the problem, each element in the list must be summed with all the elements to the left and all those to the right. As we advance with the outer loop we perform the summing for all right-hand elements (because of the commutativity of addition). All elements to the right of an element will eventually be tested with it as the loop advances.

To sum with all the elements to the left we can replace the inner loop with a hash table indexed by the elements seen already. We can then use the fact that `a + x = target`, therefore, `x = target - a` to check for the presence of `x` in the hash table.

Pseudocode:

```
def solution(list, target)
  var hash <- hashtable: [integer:boolean]
  for each element in list
    if hash has sum-element
      return true
    else
      add element to hash
    endif 
  loop
end def
```

Code:

```js
function solution(list, target) {
    const hash = new Set;
    for(let e of list) {
        if(hash.has(target-e)) {
            return true;
        }
        hash.add(e);
    }
    return false;
}

solution([1,2,3,4,5], 3);
```